# MySQL variable string query only works for numbers not text

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table called Customers and in this table I have a field of type VARCHAR called Address.

I have an html form which asks the user to type in some text which will then be used to search for any records which contain that text in the address field. This is the code:

```
<FORM NAME ="addressform" METHOD ="POST" ACTION ="address.php">
Address:<INPUT TYPE = 'TEXT' Name ='Address'  value="<?PHP print $Address; ?>">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1"  VALUE = "Search">
</FORM>
```

This passes the input entered by the user to the address.php file with the variable $Address

In the address.php file I am running this SQL query:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Address LIKE '%$Address%'";
```

What I want it to do is return all records that contain the string that the user entered.

Here's my problem: It works perfectly if the user enters only numbers, but it returns nothing if the user enters text characters.

If anyone can give me any clues as to why it is doing this it will be much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your code:
1. XSS (HTML injection)
2. SQL injection.

To prevent the HTML injection, you have to escape variables that you print.

To prevent SQL injection you have to use prepared statements (a better way) or escape function.

Prepared statement would look like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Address LIKE ?';
$stmt->execute(['%' . $Address . '%']);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Mysqli supports prepared statements too.

If you use mysql_query, use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) function, but you should strongly consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This is just to make it more secure or do you think this can fix my problem Im having?

Comment: apostrophe is the $Address would break your query.

Comment: Which apostrophe? Can you explain please?

Comment: example: $Address = "O'hare airport"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem. My problem was I was using the quote_smart funtion to protect against SQL injection attacks.

```
$Address= quote_smart($Address, $db_handle);
```

This then puts my typed text in between ',s but it doesn't do this if I enter just numbers.

Thanks to all who offered suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
   $SQL = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Address LIKE '%".$Address."%'";

Comment: Tried that and now the query doesn't return anything at all. Not even if I put in numbers.